# JvectorMap get MapObject in angularJs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jvectormap

I'm trying to access a JvectorMap in an angularJs directive.

After I create a map, I need a way to get the mapobject. In Jquery I get this with:

```
var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

But if I create an angularJs directive like:

```
app.directive('map', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).width('auto')
            $(element).height(400)
            $(element).vectorMap();              
    }
};
});
```

How can I get the mapObject?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/PwWqU/7/